# How to change default matchbox-keyboard to extended via ssh without physical keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a touchscreen and I am unable to type commands like matchbox-keyboard because the keyboard, by default doesn't have the "-" character. I want to display the extended version with all possible keys. I want to make this the default.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I created a .sh file with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script toggle the virtual keyboard
PID=`pidof matchbox-keyboard`
if [ ! -e $PID ]; then
  killall matchbox-keyboard
else
 matchbox-keyboard extended&
fi
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.